# ¿Cómo pongo un mensaje de error cuando busco un anime que no existe?

Tags: javascript

Está sería la función de búsqueda y quiero que al buscar, por ejemplo, "*asajdhais*", salga un error de que ese anime no existe.
Soy novato en esto y tengo poca idea la verdad.

```javascript
const base_url = "https://api.jikan.moe/v3";


function searchAnime(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    const form = new FormData(this);
    const query = form.get("search");

    fetch(`${base_url}/search/anime?q=${query}&page=1`)
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(updateDom)
    .catch(err=>console.warn(err.message));
    
    
}

function updateDom(data){

    const searchResults = document.getElementById('search-results');

    const animeByCategories = data.results
        .reduce((acc, anime)=>{

            const {type} = anime;
            if(acc[type] === undefined) acc[type] = [];
            acc[type].push(anime);
            return acc;

        }, {});

        searchResults.innerHTML = Object.keys(animeByCategories).map(key=>{

            const animesHTML = animeByCategories[key]
            .sort((a,b)=>a.episodes-b.episodes)
            .map(anime=>{
                return `
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-image">
                            <img src="${anime.image_url}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <span class="card-title">${anime.title}</span>
                            <p>${anime.synopsis}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-action">
                            <a href="${anime.url}">Find out more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                `
            }).join("");


            return `
                <section>
                    <h3>${key.toUpperCase()}</h3>
                    <div class="kemicofa-row">${animesHTML}</div>
                </section>
            `
        }).join("");
}

function pageLoaded(){
    const form = document.getElementById('search_form');
    form.addEventListener("submit", searchAnime);
}


window.addEventListener("load", pageLoaded);
```

Ese sería todo el código, básicamente es una web de búsqueda para encontrar anime, basado en `JIKANAPI`, una API de animes. Y lo que quiero es que al buscar un anime que no existe me salga el error de búsqueda. He intentado a poner lo que se me ocurría, pero se me rompía el código y no daba resultado.

Comment: Depende de que estes devolviendo en la busqueda, pero basicamente, tendras que crear un `if` que compruebe esa respuesta, podrias poner que si no existe el anime devuelva un valor `0` o `false` o `no encontrado` o algo asi y el `if` controle eso.

Comment: Es que al añadirlo me rompe el código y ya no devuelve nada, no se si lo estoy poniendo en el lugar equivocado o lo pongo mal directamente.

Comment: que te devuelve el archivo al que llamas?

Comment: Ahi he subido todo el codigo que tengo.

Comment: He mirado la documentación un poquito por encima, para empezar... la `V3` de la API que usas está deprecada... el 1 de octubre de este año la van a quitar, siendo inaccesible. [Documento oficial](https://docs.google.com/document/d/172RQ9wWiXqOnGqjXrV3cxMNceiqwCjxjprSFuyLwQJM/edit) que explica esto. Yo de ti antes de nada, migraba lo que tengas para funcionar con la `V4`

Comment: Nono, si este trabajo lo entrego mañana, o sea que no importa que la quiten el 1 de octubre. Y hacen usar esta version.

Comment: El problema es que no encuentro documentación de la API en la `V3`... y sin ella no puedo ayudarte, dado que no sé que responde la API ni como

Comment: Están estos documentos: https://jikan.docs.apiary.io/#introduction/information/links
No sé si con eso me podrias ayudar...

Comment: ¿De dónde has sacado que las requests son por ejemplo: `https://api.jikan.moe/v3/search/anime?q=doraemon&page=1`? Porque tanto la documentación de la `V4` que he encontrado yo, como la de la `V3` que me acabas de mandar (Aunque creo que no es la `V3`) utilizan requests de este estilo: `https://api.jikan.moe/v3/anime/8`

Comment: Hay algunos parametros que nos lo daban en la practica como predeterminados. Como ese por ejemplo. Pero supongo que funcionan igual.

Comment: Llevo un rato intentando hacer pruebas para entender que devuelve la API y no consigo entenderlo… Porque si hago una búsqueda de "dsadangsufs" me retorna igualmente cosas sin decir que no lo encuentra o algún error o algo… así que sin una Doc. que me explique que hace más a fondo, yo no puedo ayudarte.

Comment: Ejemplos de retornos: [Tu Request con algo que no existe](https://api.jikan.moe/v3/search/anime?q=sdnassa&page=1), [Ejemplo Doc. `V3` con algo que no existe](https://api.jikan.moe/v3/anime/99999999999) y [Ejemplo Doc. `V4` con algo que no existe](https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime/99999999999). ¿Ves como esos retornan un  `error 404`?, esto podrias usarlo para condicionar tu resultado... pero el URL que usas tu no retorna siempre alguna cantidad de animes, impidiendonos saber existe o no existe lo que se esta buscando.

Comment: O sea que no se puede hacer lo que me piden xd. Y si hiciera el traspaso a V4 tendria que cambiar todo el codigo de nuevo?

Comment: Hombre.. todo no creo, pero una parte almenos si, no creo que sea gran cosa. Amoldar lo que tienes al return del otro.

Comment: Empezando con la base de que no tengo ni idea de JavaScript se me hace dificil.

Comment: hmm... pues empieza entonces xD JS es facil

Comment: Buen, gracias igualmente xd

Comment: Una manera fácil es en el Object.keys(animeByCategories) comprobar el length, si es 0 pues mandas mensaje de que no se ha encontrado nada, si es más de 0 pues devuelves el resultado. Lo puedes comprobar así: ! Object.keys(animeByCategories).length ? 'No hay animes' : resto del html con los animes encontrados;  Este codigo que he escrito es como un if/else,pero reducido. Espero haberte ayudado!

Comment: @user246049, si te hubieras molestado en leer lo que he puesto, los ejemplos que he mandado y en hacer pruebas, verias que escribiendo tu comentario has perdido el tiempo y no sirve de nada...